# Hide and open div under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble opening and closing a particular search bar.

I need to open a div while focus is in the field and take it out while it does not, but when you click on the div that is open the focus of the field can not be removed or closed.

I tried putting the event in the body, in a higher div however it did not work it continues to close.

Here is the code I have used:

```
$("input[name='search-input']").blur( function() {
     $(".divCompleteSearch").addClass('hiddendiv');
});

$("input[name='search-input']").focus( function() {
    $(".divCompleteSearch").removeClass('hiddendiv');
});

$(".button-search").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("input[name='search-input']").focus();
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="row align-content-center">
    <div class="col search-bar">
        <div class="col m1 icon-search-bar">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"
                 style="height: 22px; width: 22px; display: block; fill: currentcolor;">
                <path
                    d="m2.5 7c0-2.5 2-4.5 4.5-4.5s4.5 2 4.5 4.5-2 4.5-4.5 4.5-4.5-2-4.5-4.5m13.1 6.9-2.8-2.9c.7-1.1 1.2-2.5 1.2-4 0-3.9-3.1-7-7-7s-7 3.1-7 7 3.1 7 7 7c1.5 0 2.9-.5 4-1.2l2.9 2.8c.2.3.5.4.9.4.3 0 .6-.1.8-.4.5-.5.5-1.2 0-1.7"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="col m11 input-search-bar">
            <input type="text" name="search-input" placeholder="Experimente Colegio São Fransisco">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row align-content-center divCompleteSearch hiddendiv">
    <div class="col complete-search">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col m3 button-search active">
                Escolas
            </div>
            <div class="col m3 button-search">
                Bairro
            </div>
            <div class="col m3 button-search">
                Telefone
            </div>
            <div class="col m3 button-search">
                Apelido
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

In this first image is the `div` closed, when there is the focus in the`input search` it should open the second image, the `div` should remain open until it clicks anywhere that is not inside the`div` open.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `blur` event and listen to any clicks on the page.

If you look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0phf8kbL/1/), notice that I wrapped all the HTML in a container named `#search-container`.
Then in the Javascript, I removed the `blur()` method and added a `mouseup()` listener on the whole document.

The `mouseup()` event checks if the user clicked on the container or one of it's children. If not, it closes the div.

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) 
{
    var container = $("#search-container");

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        $(".divCompleteSearch").addClass('hiddendiv');
    }
});

$("input[name='search-input']").focus( function() {
    $(".divCompleteSearch").removeClass('hiddendiv');
});

$(".button-search").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("input[name='search-input']").focus();
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.hiddendiv { display: none; }

#search-container {
  border:1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="search-container">
<div class="row align-content-center">
   <div class="col search-bar">
      <div class="col m1 icon-search-bar">
         <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"
            style="height: 22px; width: 22px; display: block; fill: currentcolor;">
            <path
               d="m2.5 7c0-2.5 2-4.5 4.5-4.5s4.5 2 4.5 4.5-2 4.5-4.5 4.5-4.5-2-4.5-4.5m13.1 6.9-2.8-2.9c.7-1.1 1.2-2.5 1.2-4 0-3.9-3.1-7-7-7s-7 3.1-7 7 3.1 7 7 7c1.5 0 2.9-.5 4-1.2l2.9 2.8c.2.3.5.4.9.4.3 0 .6-.1.8-.4.5-.5.5-1.2 0-1.7"></path>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="col m11 input-search-bar">
         <input type="text" name="search-input" placeholder="Experimente Colegio São Fransisco">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row align-content-center divCompleteSearch hiddendiv">
   <div class="col complete-search">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col m3 button-search active">
            Escolas
         </div>
         <div class="col m3 button-search">
            Bairro
         </div>
         <div class="col m3 button-search">
            Telefone
         </div>
         <div class="col m3 button-search">
            Apelido
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your test here in stackoverflow was incomplete, you used class in id place among others, can you upgrade?

Comment: Another problem I'm not able to understand is that when I click on the top it does not work and when it's underneath everything works. Do you know why ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, my test is incomplete? For your other question, it also works when you click above: https://jsfiddle.net/0phf8kbL/2/

Comment: I found the kkkk error, it was in my css with a margin inside the container. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, margin and padding will be considered as part of the container so when you click on it, it will detect the same element.